# Add Arraylists together created by a method call

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, method-invocation

I know that there are a few question already in this forum relating to my question, but none of them really seems the help me.

Since I am new to Coding I am still trying to figure out what exactly `getClass()` and `getMethod()` calls help me with.

**What I want to accomplish:**

```
// init:
List<Preview> listPreview;
List<Preview> listTemp;

// now create the Lists (from a Database)
listPreview = dbHelper.getPreview("Hero", "Axe");
listTemp = dbHelper.getPreview("Hero", "Beastmaster");

// now I want to add ListTemp to ListPreview
Class myClass = listPreview.getClass();
Method m = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("add", new Class[] {Object.class});
m.invoke(listTemp, 2);
```

**The Problem:**

Obviously this is not working right now, **but I think the idea is pretty straight forward. I want to add *listTemp* to *listPreview*.** The `getDeclaredMethod` is already considered a undeclared exception I do not really understand why.

Comment: why you're tying to use method-invocation instead of using the public api ??

Comment: `m.invoke(listTemp, 2)` is adding the element `2` to `listTemp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add two list one after another just use this:

```
 listPreview.addAll(listTemp);
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the answer, I just did no know that commend!

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively simple. Why don't you use `listPreview.addAll(listTemp);`. This will add all the elements in `listTemp` to `listPreview`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the answer, I just did no know that commend! @Arahasya was faster though :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the elements of List with your approach, use the below code.

```
Class myClass = listPreview.getClass();
Method m = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("addAll", Collection.class);
m.invoke(listPreview, listTemp);
```

OR
For a simpler way, you can use

```
listPreview.addAll(listTemp);
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the answer, I just did no know that commend! @Arahasya was faster though :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is

> getDeclaredMethod is already considered a undeclared exception

Which means there are unreporteds exception must be caught or declared to be thrown.

so below is a complete sample:

```
         try {
           Class myClass = listPreview.getClass();
           Method m = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("addAll", Collection.class);
           m.invoke(listPreview, listTemp);
         }
         catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
         }
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the answer, I just did no know that commend! @Arahasya was faster though :)